# Como reconhecer objetos específicos numa imagem com PHP?

Tags: php, processamento-de-imagens

Olá estou nesse momento na Hackathon Google I/O e o desafio é montar um software que identifique o fruto do CACAU numa imagem de lavouras, a pergunta é : Como farei isso usando php ?

Comment: Você pode dar uma olhada nas libs: [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.image.php)

Comment: @JoãoSobral nem rola cara, li as libs do php e nao vi nada efetivo.. eu vi algo sobre Open CV mas ainda estou em busca..

Comment: Bem, existe o Google Vision API (https://cloud.google.com/vision/), que permite identificar coisas na imagem. Não sei se é útil.

Comment: @Inkeliz Boa man ! mas levando em conta o Google I/O tem um tempo pequeno para exigir de nós grandes feitos, o google vision necessita de cartão de credito, e estou sem nenhum aqui .. aí complica... mas boa sugestão ! vou testar depois